# Can I develop Python code (for other platforms) on an iPad?

Tags: python, ipad

I will be doing some light-weight traveling in the near future.  I will not have any scheduled development work while I'm traveling but may be called on to tweak some Python applications.  For convenience, I'm considering carrying an iPad instead of a Windows computer.

The libraries I'm most concerned with are sqlite3, csv, xlrd, openpyxl, cherrypy.  Also, pyodbc, although I assume that's out of the question (and I wouldn't have a SQL Server instance to talk to anyway).  For testing, I would ideally be able to run cherrypy on the iPad and have the browser interact with localhost.  All my development work uses Python 2.7.

My question is whether the Python stack and library support on the iPad is sufficient for me to reasonably expect to perform small-scale programming as described.

**Please note, I do *not* want to develop programs that will run on and be distributed for the iPad (except for my own use during testing), the target systems are all Windows or Ubuntu systems.**

Comment: If it has a text editor you can.

Comment: ssh you know you want it

Comment: @martineua: I'll need to test, not just write the code.

Comment: @Jakob: may have to do some of the work without internet access (will be using a wifi iPad, and will not always have access).  I have other projects for which I would definitely have to remote in, I can't help those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) is a nice Python development environment for the iPad. It supports most of the Python standard library, as well as some other common Python libraries.

However, due to Apple's restrictions, it is not possible to install other libraries. So you won't have all libraries that you need. There is also no support for version control systems.

Comment: Pure-Python modules can be downloaded and will work inside Pythonista.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, sort of. There is no UI to download modules, and no setuptools. But you are right, in some cases, one can write (or copy & paste) code to download modules and perform the necessary installation checks,

Comment: There has been some recent hacking on setup tools. I haven't tried it yet but plan to; http://omz-forums.appspot.com/pythonista/post/5810806411231232